# I want to Handle Registrations Separately (using Node.js) for my Php web application

Tags: php, database, node.js, web-services

As I have mentioned in the title "I want to Handle Registrations Separately (using Node.js) for my Php web application" Currently we are using codeigniter for our app, but we want to reduce the load on our application by separating the registration module. Please let me know how to do that? and Is it really a good idea? what problems can I face in future.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but first ask yourself: Do you REALLY need node.js to accomplish this? node.js does one thing really well, and that is "non-blocking i/o" (I quote that because I believe it to be a myth), which to me doesn't make sense for user registrations. I would stick with a raw codeigniter approach.

Comment: This venture is unlikely to do you any good.

Comment: What ever you guys have said is right.. But I don't really have a choice here.. I have to do it... :( So any suggestions/solutions please?

Comment: Tell your leadership to suck a fatty. That's the mean way. The second way is to push back if you can. Do some research into what a good usecase for node.js is and present that. If you have 1k people signing up at the same time via facebook logon, you might have a valid case, else going through the pain of this won't be worth the time.

Comment: Can you give more information. Is the registration page on a different URL/domain.. Or if you just want the request come in as ajax call to a different port where node is running!?

Comment: The registration page should be on the same domain/URL. Is there any way I can use RESTful web services or ajax call?